# Not able to access the Neo4j through Rest (HTTP)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am currently using Neo4j 3.2 version. I can access the Neo4j through browser **localhost:7474/browser**, but when I am trying to access it through REST **http://localhost:7474** it gives an error like **Activity Invocation Failed**.

Do I need to make any changes in conf file to access it from REST? or Does it have separate authorization when access from REST?

Comment: I am using this url  http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit for REST

Comment: By default you will need to authenticate, are you using the headers described in https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/authentication/ ?

Comment: Yes. Do I need to update in conf file to access it through REST?

Answer (score 0):

You might try a bolt connection, as this is the preferred method promoted by Neo4j. The following Python code may be helpful. Q is the cypher query and ResultType defines the nature of the result to be processed (nodes, list, collections, etc.):

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase
def CypherBoltQuery(Q,ResultType):
    uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
    driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "your password"))
    with driver.session() as session:
        with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
            for record in tx.run(Q):
                for r in record:
                    {write processing code}
```

You need to authenticate and then run the query. I sent up the database using Neo4j Desktop and its default username is neo4j and you set your own password.